# How to get the clicked element in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, odoo, odoo-9

```
events: {
        'click #shop_detail_td':  'click_shop_detail_td'
    },
click_shop_detail_td: function(){}`
```

In Backbone.js we define events as above. I have the td elements with same id as "shop_detail_td". Now I want to highlight the exact td which was clicked. Is there a way possible to do this?
In JQuery we simply use this keyword to refer to the clicked element. How to do the same in the above case using Backbone?
Please help anyone.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `event` object is passed to your function.

```
click_shop_detail_td:function(e){
    var td = $(e.currentTarget);
}
```